# get JSON data from RPC object php5.5

Tags: php, json, curl, rpc

I have a RPC server class that accepts JSON data from an unspecified given 3rd party using cURL.

I can see the data hit my class, I can store a var_dump into a for what appears to be the server request, but the output looks like receiving webserver info with references to the inbound object.
But I do not see my JSON data 'foo:bar'

```
<?php
class jsonRPCServer {
        public static function handle($object) {
                if (
                        $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST' ||
                        empty($_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE']) ||
                        $_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE'] != 'application/json'
                        ) {
                        return false;
                }
                $request = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);
                $args=func_get_args();
                ob_start();
                var_dump($_SERVER);
                $result2 = ob_get_clean();
                $file = 'stripedump.txt';
                $current = file_get_contents($file);
                $current .= $result2;
                file_put_contents($file, $current);
                try {
                        if ($result = @call_user_func_array(array($object,$request['method']),$request['params'])) {
                                $response = array (
                                                                        'id' => $request['id'],
                                                                        'result' => $result,
                                                                        'error' => NULL
                                                                        );
                        } else {
                                $response = array (
                                                                        'id' => $request['id'],
                                                                        'result' => NULL,
                                                                        'error' => 'unknown method or incorrect parameters'
                                                                        );
                        }
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                        $response = array (
                                                                'id' => $request['id'],
                                                                'result' => NULL,
                                                                'error' => $e->getMessage()
                                                                );
                }
                if (!empty($request['id'])) { // notifications don't want response
                        header('content-type: text/javascript');
                        echo json_encode($response);
                }
                return true;
        }
}
?>


<?php
require_once 'example.php';
require_once 'jsonRPCServer.php';
$myExample = new example();
jsonRPCServer::handle($myExample)
    or print 'no request';
echo '<b>Attempt to perform basic operations</b><br />'."\n";
try {
    echo 'Your name is <i>'.$myExample->giveMeSomeData('name').'</i><br />'."\n";
    $myExample->changeYourState('I am using this funnction from the local environement');
    echo 'Your status request has been accepted<br />'."\n";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo nl2br($e->getMessage()).'<br />'."\n";
}
var_dump($myExample);
echo '<br /><b>Attempt to store strategic data</b><br />'."\n";
try {
    $myExample->writeSomething('bite me');
    echo 'Strategic data succefully stored';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo nl2br($e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

output from remote cURL client:

```
gentoo-mini htdocs # curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{foo:bar}" http://nyctelecomm.com/hooker/
<b>Attempt to perform basic operations</b><br />
Your name is <i>Bubba</i><br />
Your status request has been accepted<br />
object(example)#1 (1) {
  ["someData":"example":private]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "Bubba"
    ["attr"]=>
    string(17) "Some me Attribute"
  }
}
<br /><b>Attempt to store strategic data</b><br />
Strategic data succefully stored
```

stored var_dump($_SERVER) data:

```
array(29) {
  ["HTTP_HOST"]=>
  string(15) "nyccomm.com"
  ["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]=>
  string(11) "curl/7.42.1"
  ["HTTP_ACCEPT"]=>
  string(3) "*/*"
  ["CONTENT_TYPE"]=>
  string(16) "application/json"
  ["CONTENT_LENGTH"]=>
  string(1) "9"
  ["PATH"]=>
  string(29) "/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin"
  ["LD_LIBRARY_PATH"]=>
  string(29) "/usr/local/lib:/usr/local/lib"
  ["SERVER_SIGNATURE"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["SERVER_SOFTWARE"]=>
  string(34) "Apache/2.4.12 (FreeBSD) PHP/5.6.10"
  ["SERVER_NAME"]=>
  string(15) "nyccomm.com"
  ["SERVER_ADDR"]=>
  string(13) "108.61.175.20"
  ["SERVER_PORT"]=>
  string(2) "80"
  ["REMOTE_ADDR"]=>
  string(12) "67.82.49.236"
  ["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]=>
  string(21) "/home/www"
  ["REQUEST_SCHEME"]=>
  string(4) "http"
  ["CONTEXT_PREFIX"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT"]=>
  string(21) "/home/www"
  ["SERVER_ADMIN"]=>
  string(19) "admin@ex-mailer.com"
  ["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]=>
  string(38) "/home/www/hooker/index.php"
  ["REMOTE_PORT"]=>
  string(5) "52841"
  ["GATEWAY_INTERFACE"]=>
  string(7) "CGI/1.1"
  ["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]=>
  string(8) "HTTP/1.1"
  ["REQUEST_METHOD"]=>
  string(4) "POST"
  ["QUERY_STRING"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["REQUEST_URI"]=>
  string(8) "/hooker/"
  ["SCRIPT_NAME"]=>
  string(17) "/hooker/index.php"
  ["PHP_SELF"]=>
  string(17) "/hooker/index.php"
  ["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"]=>
  float(1436429001.683)
  ["REQUEST_TIME"]=>
  int(1436429001)
}
string(4) "name"
```

tcpdump:

```
00:29:06.659025 IP 192.168.0.55.52841 > 108.61.175.20.vultr.com.http: Flags [P.], seq 1:148, ack 1, win 115, options [nop,nop,TS val 2017270703 ecr 2483478707], length 147
E....A@.@.f....7l=...i.P...g.I.]...s.......
x=......POST /hooker/ HTTP/1.1
Host: nyccomm.com
User-Agent: curl/7.42.1
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 9

{foo:bar}
00:29:06.746198 IP 108.61.175.20.vultr.com.http > 192.168.0.55.52841: Flags [P.], seq 1:561, ack 148, win 1033, options [nop,nop,TS val 2483478793 ecr 2017270703], length 560
E..dm.@.5...l=.....7.P.i.I.].......     :......
...     x=..HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 09 Jul 2015 08:03:21 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.12 (FreeBSD) PHP/5.6.10
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.10
Content-Length: 373
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

<b>Attempt to perform basic operations</b><br />
Your name is <i>Bubba</i><br />
Your status request has been accepted<br />
object(example)#1 (1) {
  ["someData":"example":private]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "Bubba"
    ["attr"]=>
    string(17) "Some me Attribute"
  }
}
<br /><b>Attempt to store strategic data</b><br />
Strategic data succefully stored
00:29:06.746271 IP 192.168.0.55.52841 > 108.61.175.20.vultr.com.http: Flags [.], ack 561, win 123, options [nop,nop,TS val 2017270790 ecr 2483478793], length 0
E..4.B@.@.gP...7l=...i.P.....I.....{.W.....
```

How do I access the JSON data from my inbound RPC object? (specifically 'foo:bar')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works when used all by its self

```
<?php
        $request = file_get_contents('php://input');
        $args=func_get_args();
        ob_start();
        var_dump($request);
        $result2 = ob_get_clean();
        $file = 'stripedump.txt';
        $current = file_get_contents($file);
        $current .= $result2;
        file_put_contents($file, $current);
?>
```